# htaccess directive for subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I have (.htaccess in a root directory) fancy directory listing like:

IndexOrderDefault Descending Date

So all subfolders are listed properly (date descending), but I only want the root to list folders alphabetically (sort by name ascending) and leave subfolders as is, creating htaccess for each subfolder isn't an option, so it has to be done within root's htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set those in your vhost/server config inside a `<Directory>` and `<DirectoryMatch>`, maybe something like this:

```
<Directory "/path/to/date-order/dir">
    IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "^/path/to/date-order/dir/[^/]+/">
    IndexOrderDefault Ascending Name
</DirectoryMatch>
```

The `IndexOrderDefault Ascending Name` is default ordering.